# Javascript : dynamically changing the colour of messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am a beginner in the javascript world and need some help.
What I am trying to create is a small websocket based telemetry app.
Therefore I have installed node.js and the including libraries.

1)My question is how to send messages out to clients which change their colour to get a good overview.

2)Additionally I want to know how to clear the messages to prevent memory overload.

server.js

```js
var io = require('socket.io') (5000),
    sockets = [];

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   
   sockets.push(socket);
   socket.on('message', function (message) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
          sockets[i].send(message);
 }
}); 
 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
  if (sockets[i].id === socket.id) {
  sockets .splice(i, 1);
  }
      }
  console.log('The socket disconnected. There are ' + sockets.length + 'connected sockets');
});
  });

setInterval(function() {
 sockets.forEach(socket => {
  socket.send('Throttle' + " " + '15.5' + " " + 'WheelSpeedLeft' + " " + '643'
               + " " + 'WheelSpeedRight' + " " + '532');

         });


}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>Telemetry App</head>
   <body>
        <form id="my-form">
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
 <p>
 <button type="submit">Send</button>
     </p>
</form>

<div id="messages"></div>

<script src="http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect', function () {

  document
    .getElementById('my-form')
    .addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      socket.send(document.getElementById('message').value);
});

socket.on('message', function (message) {
var messageNode = document.createTextNode(message),
    messageElement = document.createElement('p');

    messageElement.appendChild(messageNode);
    document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(messageElement);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

comment from 6th February, 2017

```js
function trimOldMessages(limit) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < msgs.length; ++i)
   if(msgs[i]== 10)

      var msgs = document.querySelectorAll('#messages p');
      const nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('div');  // convert from a nodeList to an actual array
      msgs = Array.prototype.slice(msgs);
      while(msgs.length > limit) {
         var oldMsg = msgs.shift();
         oldMsg.parentNode.removeChild(oldMsg);
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how to send messages out to clients which change their
>   colour to get a good overview.

When you send the message from the server, you don't have to send only a string.  You can send an object that contains both your string and your desired color:

```
let msg = 'Throttle' + " " + '15.5' + " " + 'WheelSpeedLeft' + " " + '643'
                     + " " + 'WheelSpeedRight' + " " + '532';
socket.emit("message", {msg: msg, color: "blue"});
```

Note: socket.io uses the `.emit()` method not `.send()` to send data and that method takes two arguments - a message name and data.

Then, in the client, you can use that color to influence the display:

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {

    var messageNode = document.createTextNode(data.msg),
        messageElement = document.createElement('p');

    messageElement.style.color = data.color;
    messageElement.appendChild(messageNode);
    document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(messageElement);
});
```

> Additionally I want to know how to clear the messages to prevent
>   memory overload.

Usually, the strategy here is to set some upper limit of how many message you want to keep in the client and when you exceed that limit, just delete the oldest ones.

```
function trimOldMessages(limit) {
    var msgs = document.querySelectorAll('#messages p`);
    // convert from a nodeList to an actual array
    msgs = Array.prototype.slice(msgs);
    while(msgs.length > limit) {
        var oldMsg = msgs.shift();
        oldMsg.parentNode.removeChild(oldMsg);
    }
}
```

And, you could call that right after you insert a new message:

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {

    var messageNode = document.createTextNode(data.msg),
        messageElement = document.createElement('p');

    messageElement.style.color = data.color;
    messageElement.appendChild(messageNode);
    document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(messageElement);
    trimOldMessages(100);
});
```

Various observations about your code:

1. Socket.io uses `.emit()` to send a message, not `.send()`.
2. `.emit()` takes two arguments, a message name and some data.  The other end of the connection then must be listening for that message name.
3. Your interval is sending the same text over and over.  I presume you want to make that string be dynamically created from some server-side data.
4. If you just want send to all connection clients, you don't need to keep your own list of sockets for that.  Socket.io can do that automatically for you with `io.sockets.emit()`.

Comment: I know that my interval is sending same text over and over again, but I wanted it that way, because the telemetry app is just for observing to know what the small wireless car does with a telemetry box while driving every second.

When I open the index.html the debugger console says that " function trimOldMessages(limit)" is not defined.

Do I need to count the array after converting nodeList to an array?

Comment: @vceli1jn -I gave you the code for `trimOldMessges()`.  If you're getting that error, then you must not have put that code into the right place in the client file.  I can't really help debug code when you don't show the exact code you are now trying to use.

Comment: I tried to display 10 messages and after the 10th message, I want the old ones to get deleted, so I can see the new ten messages.
Otherwise I need to scroll down to see the newest telemetry data.

My code is :

Comment: @vceli1jn - Did this answer your question?  If it did, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn your some reputation points for following the proper procedure here on stack overflow.